# ¿Como retorno 2 array al success de Ajax?

Tags: codeigniter

Controlador....

```
    function getCompetencias(){
        $query['competencia'] = $this->studentCompetencias_model->getCompetencias();
        $encon = json_encode($query);

        $student = $_POST['alumno'];
        $teacher = $_POST['clase'];
        $queryA['atributo'] = $this->studentCompetencias_model->getAtributos($student,$teacher);
        $enconA = json_encode($queryA);

        echo $encon,$enconA;
}
```

JQuery (AJAX)

```js
$.ajax
          ({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {alumno: id, clase: idAsgin},
            url: '<?= base_url()?>EvaluarCompetencias/getCompetencias',
            success: function(data){
              var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              alert(obj);
            },error: function(){
              alert("algo salio mal");
            }
          });
```

Comment: que tal si haces `echo '{"encon" :' .$encon.',"enconA" :'. $enconA.'}';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un array asociativo

```
echo json_encode( array( 'vocales'=> ['a','e','i'], 'numeros'=>[1,2,3]) );
```

Y en tu función success tendrás esta estructura que puedes trabajar facilmente

```
{"vocales":["a","e","i"],"numeros":[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: Gracias, muy buena la retroalimentación.

Answer (score 0):

Al utilizar array asociativo, y poder sacar los datos, se tienen que agregar primero, las posiciones del array, despues el nombre del array despues la posicion de los datos y al final el dato.

obj[0]['competencia'][i].dato final;